# Oracle SQL - Grouping multiple medical claims into one event

Tags: oracle, grouping

I'm trying to group multiple medical claims into one event, or inpatient stay.  To keep this simple, let's say I have a patient who goes to the hospital on 1/1/2017, is released on 1/5/2017, and is transferred to another hospital on that same day, and is released from that other hospital on 1/10/2017.

So I have two claims, one with an admit date of 1/1/2017 and discharge date of 1/5/2017, and the other claim has an admit date of 1/5/2017 and discharge date of 1/10/2017.  Because one starts right after the other, it is considered one inpatient stay.

In Oracle, I would like to combine that into one line, with an admit date of 1/1/2017, and a discharge date of 1/10/2017, based on the fact that the one claim has a discharge date of 1/5/2017, and the second claim has an admit date on that same date.

Any help on which direction to go into would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:  Please see the sample data below:

```
  CLAIM_ID   MEME_RECORD_NO  ADMIT_DATE      DISCHARGE_DATE
        1            127300   1/3/2017       1/11/2017
        2            127300  1/12/2017       1/20/2017
        3            180100   1/3/2017        1/6/2017
        4            180100   1/6/2017       1/20/2017
        5            265700   1/2/2017        1/5/2017
        6            265700   1/5/2017       1/17/2017
        7            300000   2/1/2017        2/5/2017
        8            300000   2/5/2017        2/9/2017
        9            300000   2/9/2017       2/12/2017
```

CLAIM_ID 1 and 2 are separate events, since the ADMIT_DATE for CLAIM_ID 2 is greater than the discharge date for CLAIM_ID 1 (even though they're the same patient), CLAIM_ID 3 and CLAIM_ID 4 combined is one event, since the discharge date for CLAIM_ID 3 is the same as the ADMIT_DATE for CLAIM_ID 4, and the scenario repeats itself for CLAIM_ID's 5 and 6.  For CLAIM_ID'S 7, 8 and 9, this is also one event, so all 3 would be combined.  In addition to actually grouping them, I would also like to number the rows with an EVENT_ID field

Assuming the above were a table, and I queried it, the output should be 5 events.  The final product should look like this:

```
EVENT_ID       MEME_RECORD_NO  ADMIT_DATE      DISCHARGE_DATE
    1                127300     1/3/2017       1/11/2017
    2                127300    1/12/2017       1/20/2017
    3                180100     1/3/2017       1/20/2017
    4                265700     1/2/2017       1/17/2017
    5                300000     2/1/2017       2/12/2017
```

I really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: So, in your example you want to replace two rows with one row. Do you want to do this in the base data (probably a bad idea) or in a view (much better) or simply when you report (as in a `SELECT` statement)? Then: the rows may have `patient_id`, `admit_date` and `discharge_date` columns. Don't they also have other information, such as hospital name? If they do, what should happen to **that** information?

Comment: You have to tell us more about the structure of the table, sample data would be great too.

Comment: I put some sample data in my main post.  Any help would be appreciated!